# Switching between stackexchange accounts doesn't work on Brave but works with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, cookies, forwarding, brave

My Stackexchange account was originally created on stackoverflow. That means that if I want to login to any other site, like this one, I have to use my stackoverflow credentials and then get forwarded to the site.

This works without a problem on Google Chrome but it doesn't work with the Brave Browser. It doesn't even allow me to log in at the individual sites, but logging in at stackoverflow itself works so my credentials are correct. I raised the issue [here](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/14286), but got no response yet.

Am I missing any settings I have to set? Any other Brave users here that know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you should report the problem on Meta Stack Exchange instead on Super User.

Comment: Well if it's a 4xx error then I messed up. If it's 5xx stackexchange messed up. I am not confident to say that it isn't me, so I posted here first ;)